# How can I set my outside shape's background in xml? transparent circle

Tags: android, layout, styles

How can i make style of layout with transparent circle in white rectangle?

If i make background of circle  transparent then i saw only white rectangle(I know why), any possible solve?
Like this :
[screenshot http://ipicture.kz/images/2014/07/6eijxdbpjjsstuularkx.jpg](http://ipicture.kz/images/2014/07/6eijxdbpjjsstuularkx.jpg)
**(without border)**

Comment: not in xml,  I'm afraid

Comment: Two other ways then style:
1. you can set an image like this to background of layout
2. you can creaate xml Drawable and set as layout background

Comment: You can use a 9 patch

Answer (score 0):

create a xml-drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="rectangle"
            android:useLevel="false">

            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />

        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

            android:shape="ring"
            android:thicknessRatio="2"
            android:innerRadius="0dp"
            android:useLevel="false">

            <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```